# Bash script infinitely launches processes

Tags: linux, bash

Ubuntu. The basename tool has to be installed.
Bash script is named as "basename"

```
#!/bin/bash

PROGNAME=$(basename $0)

if [[ -e $1 ]]; then
   echo -e "\nFile Type:"
   file $1
   echo -e "\nFile Status:"
   stat $1
else
   echo "$PROGNAME: usage: $PROGNAME file" >&2
   exit 1
fi
```

After launching "./basename case", where "case" is a bash script, errors occured:

```
/home/user/bin/basename: fork: retry: No child processes
/home/user/bin/basename: fork: retry: No child processes
...
/home/user/bin/basename: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

And in the end it shows the expected result.

Something tricky happens here. What is it?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I got it. basename command in third line  starts not the basename linux tool, but it starts this script recursively. So, naming scripts like standards linux programs isn't good.
To make the script works with name "basename" it have to use a full pathname to basename.

```
PROGNAME=$(/usr/bin/basename $0)
```

Comment: Publish the corrected script if you solved the question  :-)

Comment: Using the full path will fix the problem for *this* script, but as long as this script is named `basename`, every other script that tries to use `basename` will be broken. The only real solution is the change the script name to something unique.